# Have non stretchable space after title

Tags: spacing, titles, page

Consider this code:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{32pt}{12pt}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    Body.\par
    Body.\par
    \section{Section}
    Body.\par
    Body.\par
    \section{Section}
    Body.\par
    Body.\par
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

However, I wanted to have *exactly* 12pt between each title and its body, while keeping the other stretching to have the content fill the whole page.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Use `\vfil `instead of `\par`.